# Error compiling after AndroidX installation

Tags: android, androidx

I recently installed the AndroidX libraries. My problem now:

> Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"

I get an error message. My Mobile App closes after opening screen.

Comment: show us the changes to your `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? 
Go to Manifest, then add inside the application.

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:appComponentFactory="anystrings be placeholder"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">
```

Perhaps this is one of the reasons!